# Ajax success not being called

Tags: jquery, ajax

I try do to a check if the cross domain image exists or not. If it exsists it has to be added to the div with the class `photos`. Here's my code:

```
var num = 6;
for(var i = 1; i <= num; i++) {
    var ThisURL = 'http://example.com/test-0' + i + '.jpg';
    var ThisImage = '<img src="http://example.com/test-0' + i + '.jpg" />';
    CheckImage(ThisURL, ThisImage);
 }

 function CheckImage(a, b) {
    $.ajax({
        url:a,
        type:'HEAD',
        error: function(){
            // nothing
        },
        success: function(){
                $( "div.photos" ).append(b);
        }
    });
 }
```

If I do a console log within the success function it won't log anything in the console, so the function is not being called..

Any idea's?

Comment: Look at the JS console. Are there any errors? Look at the Net tab. Is the request being made? Is it getting a response? Are they what you expect? Replace `//nothing` with something useful in your `error` handler, look at the arguments the `error` function gets passed.

Comment: @Quentin the console IS logging the requests and 4 of 6 fails. What should I do with the error handler as I just want to ignore errors?

Comment: If you want to ignore errors, why are you wondering why the success function isn't called?

Comment: Is `example.com` the same as the domain the request is coming from? If not, your request is being blocked by the [Same origin policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same-origin_policy)

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan As noted in my question it is cross domain. Just found out the head returns a 304 not modified for the images that are present...

Comment: @Quentin because if the image does not exsist it doesn't have to be added on the list. The images that succeed need to be added, the ones that are not present can be ignored as I'm using it for an product database with max 6 images for each product. There is no data file telling me how many photo exsist for each photo so I have to check myself.

Comment: @JoranDenHouting — I'll rephrase: While you are trying to fix your broken code, don't ignore errors. Once you have fixed it, start ignoring the errors again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not using instead:

```
function CheckImage(a) {
    $("<img/>").one('load', function () {
        $("div.photos").append(this);
    }).attr('src',a);
}
```

Comment: Updated answer. Invalid images shouldn't fire onload event